# Duplicate instances when choosing to go to one side of the tuple

Tags: haskell

What I want to do is something like this:

```
data MyDataType = MyDataType

class HasSpecialField a where
    specialField :: a -> ByteString

instance HasSpecialField a => HasSpecialField (a, b) where
    specialField (a, b) = specialField a

instance HasSpecialField b => HasSpecialField (a, b) where
    specialField (a, b) = specialField b

instance HasSpecialField MyDataType where
    specialField _ = "Coolio"
```

That is if you have a tuple like:

```
myTuple :: (String, (Int, MyDataType))
```

You could then run `specialField myTuple` to return "Coolio".

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: In short: It isn't possible but there have been proposals that would make it possible in a clean way (ex: [instance chains](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~jgmorris/)).  Sadly, there isn't anyone working to add instance chains to GHC right now.

Answer (score 1):

`Data` could be used to accomplish this, but would not constrain the function to only types that will succeed, deferring the condition to run time.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Control.Applicative

import Data.Generics

data MyDataType = MyDataType deriving (Typeable, Data)

specialField :: Data a => a -> Maybe String
specialField = fmap (\ MyDataType -> "Coolio") . something gfindtype
```